# How to correctly setup swap/memory-limits for docker?

Tags: docker

I ran a docker container with `-m 1800m` and got a warning related to memory-swappiness capabilities and suchlike (I forget the exact warning because I don't see it now). Here's a similar warning I found on the internet:

> WARNING: Your kernel does not support memory swappiness capabilities,
>   memory swappiness discarded.

After a bunch of Googling around I found the [check-config](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh) script to check whether my system/kernel was setup for running Docker properly. Most of the things were reported "green", but the following were reported "red":

```
Optional Features:
- CONFIG_USER_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_SECCOMP: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED: missing <===== 

- CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: missing <=====

  - "zfs":
    - /dev/zfs: missing <==== 
    - zfs command: missing <==== 
    - zpool command: missing <====
```

More Googling landed my on [this article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002264365-CPU-limits-for-CGroups-are-unavailable-on-Ubuntu-16-or-CentOS-7-OVH-server). I followed the instructions given there and rebooted my kernel after appending the following params to the grub config/command-line:

```
cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1
```

Now, when I run the docker command with `-m 1800m` I don't see that warning, which is good. **However**, the `check-config` script still shows up the same things in red! This is very confusing. Is the `check-config` script not reporting the correct things? Is my system still not setup properly? Does the docker command show the warning only once, by any chance?

How can I be sure that this has been setup properly before deploying my server to production?